# Einstein product recommendation(SFMC) need training time? If it is what will be the minimum time

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein, product, tracking, einstein-recommendations

I have configured the collect tracking code for a product website and uploaded the catalog(new) through a public URL and it is working fine. There are showing counts of tracking as well in the **status** tab.

After uploading a set of new catalogs there is only a range of products showing always in both email and web recommendations.
But it is not showing recommendations based on the configured scenario and rules as well.

Also, there is no change in recommendation products for different users in the email recommendations for some logic configured.
Do einstein need training period to show the product recommendations?
Do we get recommendations in real-time after uploading the catalog, configuring scenarios and rules?

Answer (score 2):

> Best practice is to observe website behavior for at least 30 days
> before launching any predictive content logic. This 30-day monitoring
> period allows the engine to dynamically build profiles and behavioral
> intent patterns of your user base.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_pb_personalization_builder.htm&type=5

Comment: How does the audiences are selected to show email recommendations in marketing cloud?                  Does their unique address wheather email address or subscriber key, are taken from the standard dataextensions( IGO?PI) or by other methods?  how the recommendations are pretested in SFMC?